Does Logical paradoxes create time
If we assume that every statement must be true or false.
The statement:
"Tomorrow I will wake up at 6:00 am",
is neither true nor false, but is impossible to find out now.
So could we argue logically that time may be a consequence of logic indeterminism?

See here

Classic non-sequitur.

I’m voting to close this question because questions that start by assuming falsehoods can be answered by literally anything, thanks to the principle of explosion.

You start by assuming statements must be true or false, then you immediately show that your assumption is invalid by citing a statement that is neither true nor false!

Maybe a cause of logic indeterminism when the logical field is limited to things up to a time t. But suppose that god is not limited below the time, he already knows what do you would make tomorrow, so it's already true or false.

The premise

"the truth value of the proposition 'Tomorrow I will wake up at 6:00 am' is unknown"

does not lead to the conclusion that

"time is a thing that results from logical indeterminism."


This is an interesting question.
A contradiction is defined as, to say of something that both it is and it is not in the same respect AND at the same time.
So if  I'm hungry AND I'm not hungry is TRUE, these must be at different times, thereby "creating time":
I'm hungry (at 8:00 AM) AND I'm not hungry (at 10:00 AM).
It also works for space. A contradiction is defined as false in all possible worlds i.e. p & ~p cannot both be true in any given world. However, p can be true in one world and ~p can be true in another world. Schrodinger's cat, many worlds interpretation, since the cat is both dead AND alive at the same time, "creating space" as it were.
